# Prevent Body Scroll on Anchor Link but keep Anchor Link Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I'm using a Visual Composer Wordpress Shortcode to generate an Accordion. When I click on the tabpanels there is an anchor link which is linked to the panel body and opens it, however the body scrolls to the anchor link but I want to prevent the scrolling. I've already tried everything I could find such as

```
$('body, html').stop();
preventDefault();
return false;
stopPropagation();/stopImmediatePropagation();
```

However, after some trying around the only thing that is working right now, is the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#product-accordion .vc_tta-panel-title a').on('click', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Well, with this "solution" I'm getting an error, of course, for undefined e, on every click. But I can't quite understand why it would work like I want that way.

Can anyone help me and find a solution which will work error-free?

Comment: Did you try to add a parameter to function? try this `.on('click', function(e){`

Comment: yes I tried. When I do, I get the scrolling, of the body to the anchor, which I want to prevent

Answer (score 0):

You can try `stopImmediatePropagation` instead `preventDefault`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#product-accordion .vc_tta-panel-title a').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is making the body jump without animation and doenst open the tab panel bodies.

Comment: Can i see your accordion codes? Where did you take it?

Comment: it's the basic accordion code from the visual composer plugin for wordpress